# Get info random from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Tv [cat] => 1 [value] => 100 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => Laptop [cat] => 1 [value] => 200 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [title] => Phone [cat] => 1 [value] => 100 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [title] => Painting [cat] => 2 [value] => 100 ) 
)
```

I would like to get the info from one of the arrays that have a cat of 1 and a value of 100, but i want it to be random witch of the two i get.

How do i do this?

Comment: Get those elements into an array. Then grab a random value from that array.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
   $info = array(
     array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'Tv',       'category' => '1', 'value' => 100),
     array('id' => 2, 'title' => 'Laptop',   'category' => '1', 'value' => 200),
     array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'Phone',    'category' => '1', 'value' => 100),
     array('id' => 4, 'title' => 'Painting', 'category' => '2', 'value' => 100),
   );

   $candidates = array();

   foreach ($info as $arr) {
     if ($arr['category'] == '1' && $arr['value'] == 100) {
       $candidates[] = $arr;
     }
   }

   $chosen = $candidates[array_rand($candidates)];

   var_dump($chosen);
?>
```

Comment: So i tried you code, if i just copy and paste it, no problem. But if the info array is created from a sql result i get: Warning: Illegal string offset 'cat' in...
Why?

Comment: @Legarndary The "cat" key doesn't seem to exist in your SQL results. `var_dump` your SQL result to make sure

Comment: it is, but it says: ["cat"]=> string(1) "2"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is in `$array`:

```
function filterByCatAndValue($a) {
    return ($a['cat'] == 1 && $a['value'] == 100);
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($array, "filterByCatAndValue");
shuffle($filteredArray);
$randomElement = array_shift($filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion based on the following multidimensional array:

```
<?php
$multi_dim = array(
array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'Tv',       'cat' => 1, 'value' => 100),
array('id' => 2, 'title' => 'Laptop',   'cat' => 1, 'value' => 200),
array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'Phone',    'cat' => 1, 'value' => 100),
array('id' => 4, 'title' => 'Painting', 'cat' => 2, 'value' => 100),
);
$max = 0;
$call_back = function( $a ) use( &$max ){
    if ( $a['cat'] == 1 && $a['value'] == 100 ){
      $max++;
      return $a;
    }
};

$filtered = array_values( array_filter( $multi_dim,$call_back ) );
$rand = mt_rand( 0, $max -1 );  // adjust $max for zero-based array indexing
var_dump( $filtered[$rand] );
?>
```

Array_filter filters out those sub-arrays whose cat(egory) is 1 and whose value is 100.  The callback is a closure with a use variable $max that keeps track of the number of returned sub-arrays.   Passing the filtered array to array_values causes the keys of $filtered to be sequential with a starting index of zero. The manual indicates that mt_rand is a better random function (see http://php.net/mt_rand). I then use the result of that function as an index to the filtered array.